# windicss with vuejs in vscode throwing `} expectedcss(css-rcurlyexpected)`

Tags: css, vue.js, visual-studio-code, windicss

In my vuejs component I have style like this

```
<style>
.preview-page {
  .preview-section {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logo-section {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
</style>
```

Its building fine and showing correct results in browser, but on vscode its showing 2 errors
`Do not use empty rulesetscss(emptyRules)`
and
`} expectedcss(css-rcurlyexpected)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, looks like there are two issues being picked up on:

1. `Do not use empty rulesetscss(emptyRules)` is a valid complaint, since `.preview-page{}` contains no styles (although its children do). Add some styles to `.preview-page` or suppress the warning if it bothers you.
2. `} expectedcss(css-rcurlyexpected)` I assume is triggering because you have not defined `lang="scss"` in your `<style>` tag. [Here is the documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass).